# Save two string array values into single table using foreach

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

In my view i am having two types of values and i am passing into string arrays. I can't concatenate both. I am using multiselect **checkbox**..

***My code:***

```
    string[] func= { };
    string[] role= { };

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Area"]))
    func = collection["Area"].Split(',');

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Role"]))
    roles= collection["Role"].Split(',');

foreach (string pf in func )
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["role_" + func]))
        role= collection["role_" + func].Split(',');

    if (role!= null && role.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string rl in role)
        {
            prefunccpf = new prefunc();
            cpf.CID= cid;
            cpf.FID= Convert.ToInt32(func);
            cpf.RID= Convert.ToInt32(rl);

        }
    }

}
```

In this first **foreach statement**  i am checking **functions** array then it will come inside. Then Second **foreach** statement i am checking **roles** array. If **roles array** having count means it will save with roleId. But This conditions are goodly work if i select **single function**. If I select **2 and more function** the **loop** again goes to top and again come to **pref.roles**. It didn't check the already those roles are saved. it is increasing again. Actually what will do for this?

Comment: Can you describe what you expect? _It is increasing again_ what is increasing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. By using Zip function in C# i got the exact result.

**MY CODE HERE**

```
        string[] func= { };
        string[] rol= { };


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Area"]))
            func= collection["Area"].Split(',');

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Role"]))
            roles= collection["Role"].Split(',');

        var lstCombined = roles.Zip(func, (role, func) => new { Role = role, Function = func }).ToList();

       foreach (var pf in lstCombined)
        {     
                    var cpf= new prefunc
                    {
                        CID= candidateId,
                        FID= Convert.ToInt32(pf .Function),
                        RID= Convert.ToInt32(pf .Role)

                    };

         }
```